# INSERT into MySQL database with JavaScript but without Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to `INSERT` data into my MySQL database.

After some research I found out I can use something called `Node.js` to do this.

But it seems to complicated for this small thing I want to do.

Is there a way to do this only with JavaScript, without `Node.js`?

Background: In my web-based iOS app I want to integrate a `Favorite` button. When the user clicks on the `Favorite` button on any site some data get stored in my MySQL database (user id, favorited webpage, title of webpage) and the `Favorite` button changes its color to signal it's favorite and put in the favorite section.

Following problem if doing this with PHP and not JavaScript: The user have to click the `Back` button twice to get out of this page, because reloading for storing in the database created a new entry in browser history.

Or is there another solution to prevent to the user have to click the back button twice to get out of this page?

Comment: Read up on AJAX

Comment: try creating using REST API here you can find the demo 
http://findnerd.com/list/view/Web-api-to-insert-data-into-database-using-php/24365/

Comment: Why got my question downvoted? I really would like to know what I did wrong to prevent it in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications which runs on the end-users machines should never-ever have direct database access. Create a `REST API` with `PHP` (if you already using it) which handles the database operations and invoke it with `JavaScript` (this is the short explanation of `AJAX`).